# How to get the sum of a count derived column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a shipment_id, no_of_boxes, and no_of_pallets as shown below.

| shipment_id | no_of_boxes | no_of_pallets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 0 |
| 1 | 45 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 165 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 10 |

I want to sum the no_of_boxes, and no_of_pallets columns against their respective shipment_id. The columns no_of_boxes, and no_of_pallets are COUNT derived columns (calculated from a different table with JOINS).

I tried writing a subquery for this but didn't help. Below subquery is for no_of_boxes, a similar query was written for no_of_pallets.

```sql
SELECT SUM(no_of_boxes)
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(si.shipment_item_id) AS no_of_boxes
        FROM   shipment_item AS si
               JOIN shipment_item AS si
                 ON si.shipment_order_systemid = sho.system_id
               JOIN shipping_unit AS su
                 ON su.system_id = si.shipping_unit_systemid
        WHERE  su.unit LIKE 'BOX'
        GROUP  BY si.shipment_item_id,
                  su.unit) t
```

My desired result is:

| shipment_id | no_of_boxes | no_of_pallets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 68 | 1 |
| 2 | 168 | 10 |

Comment: Hi @abhinay, welcome to Stackoverflow. `select shipment_id, sum(no_of_boxes), sum(no_of_pallets) from shipments group by shipment_id;` maybe the query you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @the_spectator. The columns no_of_boxes and no_of_pallets are not available in the DB. These are something which I've derived using COUNT function from a different table. Since these are already Aggregate columns, will it accept another aggregate function (SUM in this case)?

Comment: I am afraid that your subquery does not produce the table above. It seems to be wrong too as there is no `sho` alias. If you fix these then the answer of @Alex will work fine after you replace `shipments`  in the `FROM` clause with `( ... the subquery ...) as t`

Comment: @Stefanov.sm apologies for the confusion. The subquery mentioned in my question is something which I tried, to fix the problem but it didn't. However, the exact query I've written to derive the no_of_boxes and no_of_pallets columns is something like this:            
SELECT shipment_id, 
(SELECT COUNT(si.shipment_item_id) WHERE su.unit LIKE 'BOX') as no_of_boxes

shipment_id (present in sho) and shipment_item (si) is the table which has details if the shipment has a box and/or a pallet. Based on this, I counted the occurrences of words 'BOX' and 'PALLET' in each shipment.

Comment: Then just go on like @Alex says but replace `shipments` in the FROM clause with `( ... your subquery ... ) as t`

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you want, use the following query:

```sql
SELECT shipment_id, sum(no_of_boxes), sum(no_of_pallets)
FROM shipments
GROUP BY shipment_id;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, @Alex. I believe your solution can be implemented when the no_of_boxes and no_of_pallets columns are straight forward available in the DB. However, these are the Aggregated columns. If you closely observe my question - I've derived the columns no_of_boxes and no_of_pallets using a COUNT from a different table.

Comment: Try this: select shipment_id, (select sum(*) from a where ...) as no_of_boxes, (select sum(*) from b where ...) as no_of_pallets from shipments group by shipment_id

Comment: Tried this solution but throws an error. ERROR:  function sum() does not exist
LINE 16: (SELECT SUM() FROM shipment_item as si
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 628